# How to trigger an onkeyup event that's delayed until a user pauses their typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea where people enter some text (naturally), and I want to make it so that an AJAX request is made every now and then to get some suggestions regarding what the textarea is about (like stack overflow's Related Questions, but for a textarea, not a text input). The problem is that I can't do an AJAX request at every keypress (it'd be useless and very resource consuming), and I am not sure what would be the most efficient way to do it (every X words? every X seconds? or something else?).

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .keyup() delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)

Comment: @kenorb this question was actualy first, and you referenced was considered as a duplicate of this questions, but admins did not want to close the question because the title was better and it has about 132931 views which is quite remarkable.

Comment: It doesn't matter this is older, the other one has more votes and views, see: [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/55075). The title can be always edited to the better one. They can be always [merged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/191655).

Comment: Pretty cool to see my question from 2009 being reviewed in 2016. Talk about thorough moderation.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could combine a `keypress` event handler with `setTimeout` so that you send an Ajax request a set amount of time after a keypress, cancelling and restarting the timer if another keypress occurs before the timer finishes. Assuming you have a textarea with id 'myTextArea' and an Ajax callback function called `doAjaxStuff`:

```
function addTextAreaCallback(textArea, callback, delay) {
    var timer = null;
    textArea.onkeypress = function() {
        if (timer) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = window.setTimeout( function() {
            timer = null;
            callback();
        }, delay );
    };
    textArea = null;
}

addTextAreaCallback( document.getElementById("myTextArea"), doAjaxStuff, 1000 );
```

Comment: This is the generally accepted "right" way to do this. Well said.

Comment: Thanks Tim, brilliant solution :D

Comment: use onkeyup if you want to be able to capture backspace key events.

Comment: @barkmadley: that's fine if you don't want to be able to prevent its default action. You can capture backspace key events reliably in a keypress handler and prevent the default action.

Comment: @Tim Down: The code works well but has one problem: If you Alt-Tab (in Windows) to another application while the textarea has focus, and then Alt-Tab back again, the callback function is fired. It shouldn't, because no key has been pressed. I don't know how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 22):

What you're looking for is called `debouncing`. Here is a generic algorithm in native JavaScript:

```
function debounce(fn, duration) {
  var timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, duration)
  }
}
```

And here's an example of how to use it with an `onkeyup` event:

```js
function debounce(fn, duration) {
  var timer;
  return function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, duration);
  }
}

const txt = document.querySelector('#txt')
const out = document.querySelector('#out')
const status = document.querySelector('#status')

const onReady = () => {
  txt.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    out.classList.remove('idle')
    out.classList.add('typing')
    status.textContent = 'typing...'
  })
  
  txt.addEventListener('keyup', debounce(() => {
    out.classList.remove('typing')
    out.classList.add('idle')
    status.textContent = 'idle...'
  }, 800))
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady)
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 300px;
}

input{
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#out{
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.typing{
  background: #A00;
  color: #FFF;
}

.idle{
  background: #0A0;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input id="txt" placeholder="Type here" />
  <div id="out">Status: <span id="status">waiting...</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution to me... Easy, clean and it lets you use it on every event listener you want...

Answer (score 14):

Another alternative is to use a small jQuery plugin called [bindWithDelay](http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/).  It uses the same setTimeout technique that the accepted answer has, but handles the timeouts transparently so your code is a little easier to read.  The [source code](http://github.com/bgrins/bindWithDelay/blob/master/bindWithDelay.js) can be seen on github.

```
$("#myTextArea").bindWithDelay("keypress", doAjaxStuff, 1000)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using lodash.js (or underscore.js) you can use the [debounce function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce).

Example (jQuery used for keyup):

```
$('#myTextArea').keyup(_.debounce(function() {
  alert('hello');
}, 500));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in jQuery solutions, [jQuery Suggest](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/suggest) is a good implementation.

No sense reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as I don't want to update the textarea or anything with the suggestions made. I just want to make an AJAX request to get the contents of another element in the page, every X keystrokes, or every X seconds the user is typing, or something. Just wondering what would be the most efficient option.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a `setInterval` that would monitor the textarea for changes and only perform AJAX callbacks when it detects a change is made.  every second should be fast and slow enough.

Comment: This requires setInterval to run forever. Tim's solution is much more elegant, only running when someone is actually interacting with the textbox.

Comment: run forever until the page is unloaded.  Also if you would like to provide some feedback as the user is typing my solution is better since it has the chance to send a request if the user is typing faster than one key per second.  I'm not saying Tim's solution isn't elegant, but that in some cases it is not the solution depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this functionality alot around the site and don't want to keep track of all of the setTimeout refs etc then i packaged this up into a plugin available [here](http://github.com/dougle/jQuery-Ajax-Singleton).

The plugin adds a few options to the normal $.ajax method for buffering and canceling previous ajax calls.