# How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve got a search field. Right now it searches for every keyup. So if someone types “Windows”, it will make a search with AJAX for every keyup: “W”, “Wi”, “Win”, “Wind”, “Windo”, “Window”, “Windows”.

I want to have a delay, so it only searches when the user stops typing for 200 ms.

There is no option for this in the `keyup` function, and I have tried `setTimeout`, but it didn’t work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/javascript-jquery-make-an-ajax-request-when-a-user-is-typing-in-a-textarea

Comment: If I could, I would close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I fail to see the harm in having duplicates, as long as the answers given and accepted are correct. Adding to the database of questions must be something good and something to strive for.

Comment: The harm is people in the future won't be able to benefit from the brilliant answers everyone shares if there are 100 of the same question, so closing dupes and redirecting everyone to the original question is better for finding best practices and fixes. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates for more info on why duplicates are closed.

Comment: This is way more popular than the one it was supposedly duplicating. It's better worded, it has better answers, ranks higher on google etc.. So many have benefited from this answer. In retrospect, it would have been a shame if this was closed. There are some trivial ones that are bad as duplicates, but this doesn't fall in that category.

Comment: This is a better question than the one being considered as the target that this is duplicating for one simple reason: the title of the question.

Comment: That's why Stackoverflow allows editing of questions, so they can be improved to more accurately reflect the real, more generic version of the problem as the community begins to understand the question better. The title is also probably why this question is more popular and ranks higher on Google (although, that depends, of course, on the approach someone takes to get here; the right keywords would almost certainly cause the other question to rank higher). Had the other question been improved and clarified, no doubt it would have received all the traffic this question received.

Comment: [Detect when user type done](http://sdtuts.local/detect-when-user-type-done/)

Comment: I'm amazed by how few mentions there are of "debounce". The correct answers are various implementations of debounce.

Answer (score 1330, accepted):

I use this small function for the same purpose, executing a function after the user has stopped typing for a specified amount of time or in events that fire at a high rate, like `resize`:

```js
function delay(callback, ms) {
  var timer = 0;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }, ms || 0);
  };
}


// Example usage:

$('#input').keyup(delay(function (e) {
  console.log('Time elapsed!', this.value);
}, 500));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="input">Try it:
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type something here..."/>
</label>
```

### How it works:

The `delay` function will return a wrapped function that internally handles an individual timer, in each execution the timer is restarted with the time delay provided, if multiple executions occur before this time passes, the timer will just reset and start again.

When the timer finally ends, the callback function is executed, passing the original context and arguments (in this example, the jQuery's event object, and the DOM element as `this`).

### UPDATE 2019-05-16

I have re-implemented the function using ES5 and ES6 features for modern environments:

```
function delay(fn, ms) {
  let timer = 0
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this, ...args), ms || 0)
  }
}
```

The implementation is covered with a [set of tests](https://cms.gt/debounce-tests).

For something more sophisticated, give a look to the jQuery [Typewatch](https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) plugin.

Comment: Another alternative: http://github.com/bgrins/bindWithDelay/blob/master/bindWithDelay.js.  It pretty much works the same way you described, I just found myself using that pattern a lot so implemented it as a jQuery plugin to make the syntax simpler.  Here is a demo page: http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/

Comment: How to execute the callback function immediately without delay if user presses enter key?

Comment: Additional information: The `delay` function actually return `function` datatype. So if being used other than `addEventListener`, such as call another function with a debounce, the returned result has to be called. For example: `delay(callback, 200)()`

Answer (score 70):

If you want to search after the type is done use a global variable to hold the timeout returned from your `setTimout` call and cancel it with a `clearTimeout` if it hasn't yet happend so that it won't fire the timeout except on the last `keyup` event

```
var globalTimeout = null;  
$('#id').keyup(function(){
  if(globalTimeout != null) clearTimeout(globalTimeout);  
  globalTimeout =setTimeout(SearchFunc,200);  
}   
function SearchFunc(){  
  globalTimeout = null;  
  //ajax code
}
```

Or with an anonymous function :

```
var globalTimeout = null;  
$('#id').keyup(function() {
  if (globalTimeout != null) {
    clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
  }
  globalTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    globalTimeout = null;  

    //ajax code

  }, 200);  
}
```

Answer (score 47):

Another slight enhancement on CMS's answer. To easily allow for separate delays, you can use the following:

```
function makeDelay(ms) {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
};
```

If you want to reuse the same delay, just do

```
var delay = makeDelay(250);
$(selector1).on('keyup', function() {delay(someCallback);});
$(selector2).on('keyup', function() {delay(someCallback);});
```

If you want separate delays, you can do

```
$(selector1).on('keyup', function() {makeDelay(250)(someCallback);});
$(selector2).on('keyup', function() {makeDelay(250)(someCallback);});
```

Answer (score 32):

You could also look at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), which provides utility methods like [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
$(window).resize(lazyLayout);
```

Answer (score 19):

**jQuery**:

```js
var timeout = null;
$('#input').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log($(this).val());
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type here..."/>
```

**Pure Javascript:**

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let timeout = null;

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Value:', input.value);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type here..."/>
```

Answer (score 17):

## Explanation

Use a variable to store the timeout function.  Then use [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to clear this variable of any active timeout functions, and then use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to set the active timeout function again.  We run `clearTimeout()` first, because if a user is typing "hello", we want our function to run shortly after the user presses the "o" key (and not once for each letter).

## Working Demo

Super simple approach, designed to run a function after a user has finished typing in a text field...

```js
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var timeout;
        var delay = 2000;   // 2 seconds

        $('.text-input').keyup(function(e) {
            $('#status').html("User started typing!");
            if(timeout) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                myFunction();
            }, delay);
        });

        function myFunction() {
            $('#status').html("Executing function for user!");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Status: <span id="status">Default Status</span><br>
<textarea name="text-input" class="text-input"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 15):

Based on the answer of CMS, I made this :

Put the code below after include jQuery :

```
/*
 * delayKeyup
 * http://code.azerti.net/javascript/jquery/delaykeyup.htm
 * Inspired by CMS in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay
 * Written by Gaten
 * Exemple : $("#input").delayKeyup(function(){ alert("5 secondes passed from the last event keyup."); }, 5000);
 */
(function ($) {
    $.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
        var timer = 0;
        $(this).keyup(function(){                   
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        });
        return $(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And simply use like this :

```
$('#input').delayKeyup(function(){ alert("5 secondes passed from the last event keyup."); }, 5000);
```

Careful : the $(this) variable in the function passed as a parameter does not match input

Answer (score 14):

**Delay Multi Function Calls using Labels**

This is the solution i work with. **It will delay the execution on ANY function you want**. It can be the keydown search query, maybe the quick click on previous or next buttons ( that would otherwise send multiple request if quickly clicked continuously , and be not used after all). This uses a global object that stores each execution time, and compares it with the most current request.

*So the result is that only that last click / action will actually be called, because those requests are stored in a queue, that after the X milliseconds is called if no other request with the same label exists in the queue!*

```
function delay_method(label,callback,time){
    if(typeof window.delayed_methods=="undefined"){window.delayed_methods={};}  
    delayed_methods[label]=Date.now();
    var t=delayed_methods[label];
    setTimeout(function(){ if(delayed_methods[label]!=t){return;}else{  delayed_methods[label]=""; callback();}}, time||500);
  }
```

You can set your own delay time ( its optional, defaults to 500ms). And send your function arguments in a "closure fashion".

For example if you want to call the bellow function:

```
function send_ajax(id){console.log(id);}
```

To prevent multiple send_ajax requests, you delay them **using:**

`delay_method( "check date", function(){ send_ajax(2); } ,600);`

*Every request that uses the label "check date" will only be triggered if no other request is made in the 600 miliseconds timeframe. This argument is optional*

**Label independency (calling the same target function) but run both:**

```
delay_method("check date parallel", function(){send_ajax(2);});
delay_method("check date", function(){send_ajax(2);});
```

Results in calling the same function but delay them independently because of their labels being different

Comment: This works really well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If someone like to delay the same function, and without external variable he can use the next script:

```
function MyFunction() {

    //Delaying the function execute
    if (this.timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    this.timer = window.setTimeout(function() {

        //Execute the function code here...

    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This function extends the function from Gaten's answer a bit in order to get the element back:

```
$.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
    var timer = 0;
    var el = $(this);
    $(this).keyup(function(){                   
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        callback(el)
        }, ms);
    });
    return $(this);
};

$('#input').delayKeyup(function(el){
    //alert(el.val());
    // Here I need the input element (value for ajax call) for further process
},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Us9bu/2/

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised that nobody mention the problem with multiple input in CMS's very nice snipped.

Basically, you would have to define delay variable individually for each input. Otherwise if sb put text to first input and quickly jump to other input and start typing, callback for the first one **WON'T** be called!

See the code below I came with based on other answers:

```
(function($) {
    /**
     * KeyUp with delay event setup
     * 
     * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay#answer-12581187
     * @param function callback
     * @param int ms
     */
    $.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
            $(this).keyup(function( event ){
                var srcEl = event.currentTarget;
                if( srcEl.delayTimer )
                    clearTimeout (srcEl.delayTimer );
                srcEl.delayTimer = setTimeout(function(){ callback( $(srcEl) ); }, ms);
            });

        return $(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This solution keeps setTimeout reference within input's delayTimer variable. It also passes reference of element to callback as fazzyx suggested.

Tested in IE6, 8(comp - 7), 8 and Opera 12.11.

Comment: Have tried this but can't get to work properly on the first keyup.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me where I delay the search logic operation and make a check if the value is same as entered in text field. If value is same then I go ahead and perform the operation for the data related to search value.

```
$('#searchText').on('keyup',function () {
    var searchValue = $(this).val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(searchValue == $('#searchText').val() && searchValue != null && searchValue != "") {
           // logic to fetch data based on searchValue
        }
        else if(searchValue == ''){
           // logic to load all the data
        }
    },300);
});
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected - the number of fetches is the same, just delayed by the 300ms - you need to use the clearTimeout() function on every keystroke, before executing the setTimeout()

Comment: Well, you don't need to use the clearTimeout in this case. The condition searchValue == $('#searchText').val() inside setTimeout will ensure if the value is the same as what it was 300ms ago. Let me know if this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Delay function to call up on every keyup.
**jQuery 1.7.1 or up required**

```js
jQuery.fn.keyupDelay = function( cb, delay ){
  if(delay == null){
    delay = 400;
  }
  var timer = 0;
  return $(this).on('keyup',function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( cb , delay );
  });
}
```

Usage: `$('#searchBox').keyupDelay( cb );`

Answer (score 4):

From **ES6**, one can use [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as well.

In this example, the code delays `keyup` event for 400ms after users finish typeing before calling `searchFunc` make a query request.

```js
const searchbar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const searchFunc = // any function

// wait ms (milliseconds) after user stops typing to execute func
const delayKeyUp = (() => {
    let timer = null;
    const delay = (func, ms) => {
        timer ? clearTimeout(timer): null
        timer = setTimeout(func, ms)
    }
    return delay
})();

searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const query = e.target.value;
    delayKeyUp(() => {searchFunc(query)}, 400);
})
```

Updated Typescript version:

```js
const delayKeyUp = (() => {
  let timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
  return (func: Function, ms: number) => {
    timer ? clearTimeout(timer) : null;
    timer = setTimeout(() => func(), ms);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something after a period of time and reset that timer after a specific event like `keyup`, the best solution is made with `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` methods:

```
// declare the timeout variable out of the event listener or in the global scope
var timeout = null;

$(".some-class-or-selector-to-bind-event").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timout); // this will clear the recursive unneccessary calls
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
         // do something: send an ajax or call a function here
    }, 2000);
    // wait two seconds

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution along the lines of CMS's, but solves a few key issues for me:

- Supports multiple inputs, delays can run concurrently.
- Ignores key events that didn't changed the value (like Ctrl, Alt+Tab).
- Solves a race condition (when the callback is executed and the value already changed).

```js
var delay = (function() {
    var timer = {}
      , values = {}
    return function(el) {
        var id = el.form.id + '.' + el.name
        return {
            enqueue: function(ms, cb) {
                if (values[id] == el.value) return
                if (!el.value) return
                var original = values[id] = el.value
                clearTimeout(timer[id])
                timer[id] = setTimeout(function() {
                    if (original != el.value) return // solves race condition
                    cb.apply(el)
                }, ms)
            }
        }
    }
}())
```

Usage:

```js
signup.key.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    delay(this).enqueue(300, function() {
        console.log(this.value)
    })
})
```

*The code is written in a style I enjoy, you may need to add a bunch of semicolons.*

Things to keep in mind:

- A unique id is generated based on the form id and input name, so they must be defined and unique, or you could adjust it to your situation.
- **delay** returns an object that's easy to extend for your own needs.
- The original element used for delay is bound to the callback, so `this` works as expected (like in the example).
- Empty value is ignored in the second validation.
- Watch out for **enqueue**, it expects milliseconds first, I prefer that, but you may want to switch the parameters to match `setTimeout`.

The solution I use adds another level of complexity, allowing you to cancel execution, for example, but this is a good base to build on.

Answer (score 3):

Combining [CMS answer](/a/1909508/1178314) with [Miguel's one](/a/30503848/1178314) yields a robust solution allowing concurrent delays.

```js
var delay = (function(){
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, label) {
        label = label || 'defaultTimer';
        clearTimeout(timers[label] || 0);
        timers[label] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

When you need to delay different actions independently, use the third argument.

```js
$('input.group1').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        alert('Time elapsed!');
    }, 1000, 'firstAction');
});

$('input.group2').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
        alert('Time elapsed!');
    }, 1000, '2ndAction');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Building upon CMS's answer here's new delay method which preserves 'this' in its usage:

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms, that){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback.bind(that), ms);
  };
})();
```

Usage:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
      alert('Time elapsed!');
    }, 1000, this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
mytimeout = setTimeout( expression, timeout );
```

where expression is the script to run and timeout is the time to wait in milliseconds before it runs - this does NOT hault the script, but simply delays execution of that part until the timeout is done.

```
clearTimeout(mytimeout);
```

will reset/clear the timeout so it does not run the script in expression (like a cancel) as long as it has not yet been executed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of CMS, it just ignores the key events that doesn't change value.

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})(); 

var duplicateFilter=(function(){
  var lastContent;
  return function(content,callback){
    content=$.trim(content);
    if(content!=lastContent){
      callback(content);
    }
    lastContent=content;
  };
})();

$("#some-input").on("keyup",function(ev){

  var self=this;
  delay(function(){
    duplicateFilter($(self).val(),function(c){
        //do sth...
        console.log(c);
    });
  }, 1000 );


})
```

Answer (score 2):

User [lodash](https://lodash.com) javascript library and use _.debounce function

```
changeName: _.debounce(function (val) {
  console.log(val)                
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [bindWithDelay](http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/) jQuery plugin:

```
element.bindWithDelay(eventType, [ eventData ], handler(eventObject), timeout, throttle)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var globalTimeout = null;  
$('#search').keyup(function(){
  if(globalTimeout != null) clearTimeout(globalTimeout);  
  globalTimeout =setTimeout(SearchFunc,200);  
});
function SearchFunc(){  
  globalTimeout = null;  
  console.log('Search: '+$('#search').val());
  //ajax code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion I have written that takes care of multiple input in your form.

This function gets the Object of the input field, put in your code

```
function fieldKeyup(obj){
    //  what you want this to do

} // fieldKeyup
```

This is the actual delayCall function, takes care of multiple input fields

```
function delayCall(obj,ms,fn){
    return $(obj).each(function(){
    if ( typeof this.timer == 'undefined' ) {
       // Define an array to keep track of all fields needed delays
       // This is in order to make this a multiple delay handling     
          function
        this.timer = new Array();
    }
    var obj = this;
    if (this.timer[obj.id]){
        clearTimeout(this.timer[obj.id]);
        delete(this.timer[obj.id]);
    }

    this.timer[obj.id] = setTimeout(function(){
        fn(obj);}, ms);
    });
}; // delayCall
```

Usage:

```
$("#username").on("keyup",function(){
    delayCall($(this),500,fieldKeyup);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin.  I know that it allows you to specify a delay or a minimum number of characters.  Even if you don't end up using the plugin, looking through the code will give you some ideas on how to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i also made a piece of code for limit high frequency ajax request cause by Keyup / Keydown. Check this out:

https://github.com/raincious/jQueue

Do your query like this:

```
var q = new jQueue(function(type, name, callback) {
    return $.post("/api/account/user_existed/", {Method: type, Value: name}).done(callback);
}, 'Flush', 1500); // Make sure use Flush mode.
```

And bind event like this:

```
$('#field-username').keyup(function() {
    q.run('Username', this.val(), function() { /* calling back */ });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this today a little late but just want to put this here in case someone else needed.  just separate the function to make it reusable.  the code below will wait 1/2 second after typing stop.

```
    var timeOutVar
$(selector).on('keyup', function() {

                    clearTimeout(timeOutVar);
                    timeOutVar= setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 500);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get an global variable isApiCallingInProgress

//  check isApiCallingInProgress 
if (!isApiCallingInProgress) {
// set it to isApiCallingInProgress true
      isApiCallingInProgress = true;

      // set timeout
      setTimeout(() => {
         // Api call will go here

        // then set variable again as false
        isApiCallingInProgress = false;     
      }, 1000);
}
```