# delay ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to set timeout that will force my page not to set more than one ajax request per minute

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not set, but send more than one

Comment: Are you looking to queue requests that come in during that minute, or discard them?

Comment: Are all the requests coming from your code, or do you mean block AJAX calls made by external script as well?

Comment: See this delay_method that allows you to give labels to execution queues http://stackoverflow.com/a/30503848/1834212

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple variable holding the timerId returned from setTimeout. Something like this:

```
var timerId;
var doRequest = function(){
  if(timerId) return;
  timerId = setTimeout(doRequest, 60*1000);
  // ajax code here
};
```

This will throttle the request to once per minute. If you need to stop the setTimeout call, then simply add another boolean based off the user event you are watching for.