# Using PrimeFaces <p:ajax>, fire up Ajax in inputText only on keystrokes that change the field

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces

I am using **PrimeFaces** and have a **p:inputText** field where I need to update some components on the view based on the latest keystroke inside that **p:inputText**.
Here's the code:

```
<p:inputText value="#{customerLController.surnameFilterConstraint}"
             id="surnamefilterfield">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" 
            update=":custForm:custDataTable"
            listener="#{customerLController.focusSurname}"
            oncomplete="primeFacesId('surnamefilterfield')"/>
</p:inputText>
```

The thing is, the above code fires up Ajax even in the case of arrow keystrokes (which I would rather avoid given the costly **update**). Ideally I would like a different version of **p:ajax event="change"** with the qualification that change is pronounced on keystrokes and not when the user hits *Enter* (which is what happens now).

If the **p:ajax** component doesn't allow a way to filter out certain **keyup** events, then I gather that the only (?) alternative would be to call JavaScript on the client side and then implement the Ajax call in Javascript but then I would forsake the convenience of using the PrimeFaces **p:ajax** component, wouldn't I?

Comment: im not familiar with PrimeFaces, but if you can subscribe to the `keypress` instead of `keyup` event, it should fix this problem. key press will only fire for keys that map directly to a printable character.

Comment: no, that doesn't do the trick, at least not in Firefox and Konkeror that I tried.

Comment: There is an answer right here at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401218/primefaces-keyup-event-delay

Answer (score 2):

Since JSF 2.2, I am using elegant way to solve this issue.

Solution is based on combination of `p:remoteCommand` (as pointed out in one of comments) and  namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough` which allows you to define native HTML [event attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) in JSF components.

In this case it would be:

1. First add new namespace to your page

   ```
   xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
   ```
2. Modify `p:inputText` and add `p:remoteCommand`

   ```
   <p:inputText id="surnamefilterfield" 
             value="#{customerLController.surnameFilterConstraint}" 
             pt:onkeyup="onKeyUpFilterKeyCode(event)"/>
   <p:remoteCommand delay="300" name="onFilteredKeyUp" 
                 actionListener="#{customerLController.focusSurname}" />
   ```
3. add JavaScript function

   ```
      function onKeyUpFilterKeyCode(event){
           var keyCode=event.keyCode;
           console.log("Key code = " + keyCode);
           //if key is not ENTER and not cursor/arrow keys
           if ((keyCode != 13) && !((keyCode >= 37) && keyCode <= 40)){
               //call remoteCommand
               onFilteredKeyUp();
           }
       }
   ```

(since this JS function contains "special" XML chars follow [BalusC recommendations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Writing_JavaScript_for_HTML) about how to add it to JSF/XML web page)

The advantage of this approach is that you can ajaxify any native HTML event supported by component (and WEB browser) while still using JSF/Primefaces components and "JSF way" of creating WEB pages.