# How to delay a commandLink in jsf with javascript or primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, commandlink

I have a commandLink which calls a backend page bean method. but I want to make a delay before it calls that method. How to do this using javascipt or primefaces?

Comment: have a look on [primefaces keyup event delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401218/primefaces-keyup-event-delay) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces offers `p:remoteCommand`. It can be called via javascript and execute, do action and ajax process and updates. Use the `p:commandLink` to call a javascript function with a `timeout`. In short

```
<p:commandLink onclick="delayIt()" />

<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandName" ... action ... update ... process/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var delayIt = function(){
       setTimeout( remoteCommandName,5000) //don't write () as it would execute it immediately
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In primefaces try 'delay' as attribute. delay is null as default.

```
<p:commandLink id="clid" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" delay="1000">
    <h:outputText value="text" />
</p:commandLink>
```