# How to add delay to filter function on keyup event in Primefaces?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have right now this function in my view, using Primefaces (6.2):

```
<p:inputText id="globalFilter" style="width:150px" onkeyup="PF('#{widgetVar}').filter()" placeholder="Searching..."/>
```

The filter function is fired right on the first keyup, so the user can't even enter 2-3 characters, which is bad.

How can I add some delay to it? As far as I saw there in no "delay" option on p:inputText, only on ajax events, but sadly I don't know how to rewrite it, to use this PF function AND ajax event...

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is Primefaces, not jQuery

Comment: PrimeFaces uses jQuery for its components.

Comment: I know that, but this information is not helping me :(

Comment: Why not? The `onkeyup` attribute will take a JavaScript function (just as with plain HTML). You can do exactly the same as answered on the duplicate.

Comment: Will this work with my PF('#{widgetVar}').filter() function as well?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Can+I+use+EL+in+JavaScript

Comment: Try with `<input type="text" onKeyUp="alert('hi'); " />` and you have the same problem. Not even a JSF issue effectively.

Comment: I don’t understand. What has to do this with Primafaces delay?

Comment: Nothing. But since your `onkeyup` is an attribute that is verbatim passed through to the plain html input on the client side, the actual question is not PrimeFaces related at all but a plain html/javascript one and you should solve it as such. This is what is done in the duplicate (with the help of jquery)..

Comment: But if you actually wanted to use a PrimeFaces ajax solution, you should have provided an attempt or even better, tried some basic searching: https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+ajax+input+delay contains enough relevant info...

Comment: And since I'm in a good mood: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401218/primefaces-keyup-event-delay

Comment: This is the simple Primefaces answer: <p:inputText id="globalFilter" style="width:150px" placeholder="Searching...">
                    <p:ajax event="keyup" delay="2000" oncomplete="PF('#{widgetVar}').filter()" />
                </p:inputText>

Comment: @VORiAND I had the same question of how to do this in PrimeFaces, and your comment about using <p:ajax delay=""> is the perfect solution. Could you make it into an answer as I wouldn't have seen it without expanding the comment section!

Comment: Thank you, but thanks to the moderators, the question was marked as duplicate, so I can't answer it anymore :)