# stop propagation if I type repeatingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I'm building a custom search engine for a website and the search is done via AJAX on keyup event, so when you start typing ( if you type more than two characters and after the string is trimmed ) an AJAX call to the server is done.

It works perfectly, but there's one scenario I was thinking about, when you start typing four or as many as you want characters in a row, there will be as many calls as characters you type. Well that's going to make a lot of requests if you type 10 characters for instance.

In this case I was thinking if there is a simple way of stopping everything what was started before when such behavior occurs and pick up the search after you're done typing insanely (:

Comment: Why not simply delay the call via Ajax until they have not typed anythning for .5 to 1 second? Then you can simply cancel a `setTimeout` etc.

Comment: You can also take a look at `Autocomplete` plugin in jQuery.. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Underscore debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) for that.
Make the key up event call undersocre's function instead of your function, that way underscore will know *when* to call your function.

Comment: @roasted Well... if you want to use Underscore *only* for that, then you may preffer making your small startTimeout-wait-cancelTimeout logic, but then you're doing 2 things: a) You're writing durty code (yes, starting and canceling a timeout isn't *that* clean.) And b) You're wasting your time. Underscore can help you with a lot of stuff in JS. Just have a look at the docs and you'll see how less code you'll need to write.

Comment: This approach sounds good, but then I have to include another library just to add this functionality (:

Comment: I just did Alexander (: Thanks for the input

Comment: Alexander, I'm binding the _.debounce function to the function I want to execute with delay, but it seems like it doesn't respond to the delay ...

Answer (score 1):

> Simply delay the call via Ajax until they have not typed anything for
>   .5 to 1 second. Then you can simply cancel a setTimeout etc.

-- @Tejs

Comment: That was my first though too (: But I wanted to be sure that there isn't any fancy method out there that could make things easier and better (:

Comment: Not really... you can't cancel the request after it has gone, so you will have to wait to some degree. You could conceivably send the first request, but then if a second key is pressed quickly, wait until 0.5s after the last key has been pressed and send the next request.

Answer (score 0):

As been said before, here's an example that executes a function after a certain specified delay, and if the method is called again when the delay hasn't passed the original timeout is cleared and a new one is set again.

This is a clean solution and it doesn't require jQuery, just alter the usage.

[How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)