# how to execute any function in jquery after few seconds on the click of any link

Tags: jquery, struts2-jquery

I have struts2 jquery grid where on click of  a row I am calling a jQuery function for  performating a struts2 action. My code is running fine.

I want to perform my jQuery function after delay of a few seconds. How can I do this?

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
 //assume this code is working fine on rowselect from my jquery grid, New Updation in it is "i want to execute or load the url  after few seconds"
     $(function(){
            $.subscribe('rowselect', function(event,data) {
                var param = (event.originalEvent.id);  
                $("#myAdvanceDivBoxx").load('<s:url action='InsertbooksToSession' namespace='/admin/setups/secure/jspHomepage/bookstransaction'/>'+"?bid="+event.originalEvent.id);  
            });  
     }); 
</script>
```

**What i tried is the below code** but am unable to get the output which i am looking for:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
 $(function(){
        $.subscribe('rowselect', function(event,data) {
            var param = (event.originalEvent.id);  
            $("#myAdvanceDivBoxx").load('<s:url action='InsertbooksToSession' namespace='/admin/setups/secure/jspHomepage/bookstransaction'/>'+"?bid="+event.originalEvent.id);  
        }).delay(9000);  
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Or delay ? http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: @Vucko delay is for animations

Comment: the best way is to something similar to answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay

Answer (score 0):

delay postpones functions chained after it.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

you just need a tried and true setTimeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: i tried but not working. Please post the  answer for my above question

Answer (score 0):

only use `delay` for some animation/effects like:

```
$("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

[**jQuery Delay**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

--

this should do the work, just use the `setTimeout` ([**docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)) and see if helps you.

```
$.subscribe('rowselect', function(event,data) {
     var param = (event.originalEvent.id);  
     setTimeout(function(){
          $("#myAdvanceDivBoxx").load('<s:url action='InsertbooksToSession' namespace='/admin/setups/secure/jspHomepage/bookstransaction'/>'+"?bid="+event.originalEvent.id);  
     }, 9000);
 });
```

Comment: did u check if setTimeout is working for you ? low down the time to 1 second and debug.