# Passing originating element to callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'm a little weak (or maybe a lot weak) with client side scripting. I am trying to implement a delayed call to do an ajax save based on waiting 500ms after the user stops typing.

I found this [great solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay). But my resulting function needs the original element that triggered the save. How can I pass this value through?

Here is my calling code:

```
$('#OrderDetailsTabs').on('keyup', 'form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] textarea', function (event) {
        var thisElement = this;
        delay(function (thisElement) {
            alert('Time elapsed!');
            saveWOHdr(thisElement);
            },
            1000);
    })
```

Here is the delay variable definition:

```
var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

saveWOHdr needs the originating element to be passed to it.

Comment: Simply remove the `thisElement` argument from the function you are passing to `delay()`. Everything else looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#OrderDetailsTabs').on('keyup', 'form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] textarea', function (event) {
        delay(function () {
            alert('Time elapsed!');
            saveWOHdr(event.target);
            },
            1000);
    })
```

Because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in JavaScript, `event` is available to the anonymous function you pass into `delay` even after your event handler function exits.  You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to figure out which element triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the result of `setTimeout` not giving any function arguments. The code you have should already work if you remove the argument from your function since it'll be `undefined` at the moment (as `setTimeout` isn't passing an argument).

```
$('#OrderDetailsTabs').on('keyup', 'form[id^="frmWorkOrderHdr"] textarea', function (event) {
    var thisElement = this;
    delay(function () {
        alert('Time elapsed!');
        saveWOHdr(thisElement);
        },
        1000);
})
```