# jQuery delay on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, keyup

I'm trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686252/772437) in my own code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#qty').delayKeyup(function() {
        var qty = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(Math.round(qty / 10) * 10);
    }, 1000);

});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
        var timer = 0;
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        });
        return $(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

but no change in the input value is occurring. If I remove the delayKeyup function the change works OK but obviously not with the delay. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that the handler function is invoked with the proper `this` value:

```
    var timer = 0, elem = this;
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback.bind(elem), ms);
    });
```

Your callback is written to expect that `this` will be the DOM element involved.

Also, it's good practice to make sure that your jQuery add-on methods behave like good jQuery citizens. In a case like this, you should be using `.each()` in case the selector for "delayKeyup" refers to multiple elements:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
        return this.each(function() { // $(this) not necessary for a jQuery add-on
          var timer = 0, elem = this;
          $(this).keyup(function(){
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback.bind(elem), ms);
          });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Not all browsers support `.bind()`, but luckily in this case there's a really simple alternative that works everywhere:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.delayKeyup = function(callback, ms){
        return this.each(function() {
          var timer = 0, elem = this;
          $(this).keyup(function(){
            clearTimeout (timer);
            timer = setTimeout( function() { callback.call(elem); }, ms);
          });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```