# jQuery callback and delayed action: scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I am working on function which is kind-of-like an auto-complete, but not quite the same.  The main difference is that the matching values returned by ajax are shown in a list in a separate div (not the input text box where the user is typing).

Anyhow, I used some code from this SO question, [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay), to get the delay working.  Essentially, on each keypress they jQuery event handler calls myDelay(), giving it a function to run, and a timeout.  If the timeout has not expired before the next keypress, the function which is set to trigger is replaced with another (and a new timeout).

My problem is that the function which I am asking to put on delay is a jQuery ajax call with a success handler.  When I change a value in the success handler, the changes are not see in the parent scope.

Here's the delay function.  It exists in the global scope.

```
var myDelay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

Here is the code that uses the delay:

```
var mySearch = {
    publicSearch : function () {
        $('#publicSearch').keypress(function () {
            myDelay(function () {
                var list;
                var term = $('#publicSearch input[type=text]').val();
                if (term) {
                    $.getJSON('/search/public', { term : term }, function (data) {

                        // assign some value to `list` here
                    })
                } else {
                    list='Please type a term to search on';
                }
                $('#publicSearch div').html(list);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

In the ajax success handler I can set the value of `list` to anything I like but it won't be seen in the parent scope.  When I call `$('#publicSearch div').html(list)` the contents of the div are set to null.

I think its just a scoping problem but I can't work it out.

Note that the code which uses the delay is in a mySearch namespace.  This is because I have several different types of searches to build and I need a mechanism for organising the code.