# Show a bootstrap popover after finish typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this field that i want to check if it's valid and i would like to show a popover if it's not the case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[name=email]').keyup(email_check);
});

function email_check(){

    $('input[name=email]').parent().removeClass("has-error has-feedback").removeClass("has-success has-feedback");
    $('span.glyphicon').remove();
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val()
if( !isValidEmailAddress( email ) ) { 

$("input[name=email]").popover({trigger: 'focus', content: "Error!", placement : 'bottom'});
$('input[name=email]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback" ).append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>");
return false;
    }else{
        $("input[name=email]").popover({trigger: 'focus', content: "Valid!", placement : 'bottom'});
        $('input[name=email]').parent().addClass( "has-success has-feedback" ).append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>");

    return true;
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the popver doesn't show until I get out of the field and focus again on it! Hope you understand what I mean! How can I fix it?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**http://bootply.com/124932**

You need to change the popover trigger to `manual`, and then use the `show` method to display the popover...

```
$("input[name=email]").popover({trigger: 'manual', content: "Error!", placement : 'bottom'});
$("input[name=email]").popover('show');
```

Comment: It works great but is there a way to show it after typing not during ?

Comment: Not really since `keyup` happens every time the user types. Check out this thread for a keyup `delay` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay