# Datatables Column Search/Filter - Double click required to open hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am using the following Datatable example, with the addition of some hyperlinks:
[Datatable Column Filter](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html#)

Example of hyperlink code added - `<td><a href="link.html">Tiger Nixon</a></td>`

Steps:

1. Search/Filter any column in the table.
2. Click on a hyperlink. -> nothing happens. (linked page should open)
3. Click on a hyperlink again. -> linked page opens.

After using the column filter, I need to un-focus the column filter by clicking within the table rows, then I can click on the hyperlink.

Question: Can this be fixed so only one click is needed?

Further info:

This looks to be a similar issue to mine but not similar enough to fix my problem:

[DataTables Column Filter Strange Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794672/datatables-column-filter-strange-behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be an easy solution to your question:

```
$("#example tfoot input").on('keyup change', function(event) {
    table
      .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
      .search( this.value )
      .draw();
    event.target.blur();
});
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColReorder/examples/initialisation/col_filter.htmll

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, my advice is to use something like

```
$(elementUsedAsFilter).blur();
```

in your change (or whatever) event handler.
`.blur()` removes focus from the handler, after that you should be good to go!
I think you should be able to get `elementUsedAsFilter` from the handler you used.

Comment: Appreciate your help with this Fabio. If possible, could you explain further how to add this to the JS in the example in my question?