# Kendo UI [DropDownList] - Filter search, show message if search item did not found

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using Kendo UI DropDownList with search filter...

How can I replace search icon with '`+ Add`' link with '`No items available`' message if searched item is not available in the dropdown...

> **[Online Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eGahE)**

Please refer the below image for more clarification...
[image]

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
        filter: "contains",
    });

    if ($('.k-list-scroller ul').length == 0){
        $('.k-list-filter .k-i-search').hide();
        $('.k-list-filter').append('<a href="#" id="newItem">+ Add</a>');
    }

    if ($('.k-list-scroller ul').length > 0){
        $('.k-list-filter .k-i-search').show();
        $('.k-list-filter #newItem').remove();
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>Products</h4>
<select id="products">
    <option>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolar</option>
    <option>Sit amet lieu</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only running your code when the page loads(*$(document).ready()*). You need to add an event handler to use your code each time that textbox updates. I was able to add a keyup event for that.

Once that's added, however, the code runs before kendo knows that the values in the dropdown have changed. Using a **[delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909508/1520969)**, we're able to hold off a moment and let the dropdown update properly.

*<sub>Note: I used 500 ms for the delay, but that number isn't **the** number.</sub>*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set up the delay function
  var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();
    
  $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
    filter: "contains"
  });

  // set up the event handler
  $(".k-list-filter input").keyup(function () {
    
    // wait for Kendo to catch up
    delay(function () {
      // check the number of items in the list and make sure we don't already have an add link
      if ($('.k-list-scroller ul > li').length === 0 && !($("#newItem").length)) {
        $('.k-list-filter .k-i-search').hide();
        $('.k-list-filter').append('<a href="#" id="newItem">+ Add</a>');
      }

      // check the number of items in the list
      if ($('.k-list-scroller ul > li').length > 0) {
        $('.k-list-filter .k-i-search').show();
        $('.k-list-filter #newItem').remove();
      }
        
    }, 500); // 500 ms delay before running code
  });    
});
```

```css
html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h4>Products</h4>
  <select id="products">
    <option>Lorem</option>
    <option>Ipsum</option>
    <option>Dolar</option>
    <option>Sit amet lieu</option>
  </select>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **@Jonathan**... Excellent... this is what I am looking for and thanks for your time and explanation.... :)