# Want to add Delay to a Keydown event

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I have found similar threads but they only talk about removing the initial delay, not setting a delay.

I have a game that moves the user accordingly if wasd is pressed and moves them to the next grid coordinate. However, if the user holds down any of the wasd keys, they shoot across nearly instantly, which I would rather not have. I have tried to create a delay in the movement, which works if you tap the key fast but not if held down. I have the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(event) {
 var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  if (canMove == true) {
   switch (keyCode) {
    case 68: //d
     keyD = true;
     canMove = false;
     break;
    case 83: //s
     keyS = true;
     canMove = false;  
     break;
    case 65: //a
     keyA = true;
     canMove = false;    
     break;
    case 87: //w
     keyW = true;
     canMove = false;
     break;
 }
setTimeout(function(){canMove = true;}, 400); 
}
checkMovement();
}
```

My problem: I can press 'a' for example and zoom across the map nearly instantly. I want their to be a delay, of say 200-500ms so that they move at a steady slow rate. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you also post the the code for achieving the zooming?

Comment: Set an interval onkeydown,  clear it onkeyup?

Comment: Did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay ?

Comment: @KK I didn't really want to use Jquery as that's unexplored territory for myself :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little demo that uses a max key repeat rate of once per 250 ms.

Click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button, **click in the blank area to give it focus**, then press <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> on your keyboard

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (function(canMove) {
  return function(event) {
    if (!canMove) return false;
    canMove = false;
    setTimeout(function() { canMove = true; }, 250);
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 68: return move("right");
      case 83: return move("down");
      case 65: return move("left");
      case 87: return move("up");
    }  
  };
})(true), false);

function move(direction) {
  console.log("move: %s", direction);
}
```

Comment: Huzzah! That works, thanks so much and sorry for the delay in affirming the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var moveListener = null;

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onKeyDown(event) {
 var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  //prevent reseting event listener on hold down also will prevent up,left diagonal type movement
  if (moveListener === null) {
    moveListener = setInterval(move(keyCode),400);
  }
}

function onKeyUp (event){
   clearInterval(moveListener);
    moveListener = null;
}

function move (direction){
 //move code here
}
```

Haven't tested it but you get the general idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
   window.addEventListener("keydown", 
             setTimeout(function(){ 
               onKeyDown()
              }, 5000) 
   , false);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;

    if (canMove == true) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case 68: //d
                    keyD = true;
                    canMove = false;
                    break;
                case 83: //s
                    keyS = true;
                    canMove = false;
                    break;
                case 65: //a
                    keyA = true;
                    canMove = false;
                    break;
                case 87: //w
                    keyW = true;
                    canMove = false;
                    break;
            }
        }, 400);
    }
    checkMovement();
}
```

try this :