# Is there a way to create a short link generator page like Bit.ly in Wordpress? I'm looking for resources, not free code

Tags: wordpress, url-shortener

I'm just seeking a place to start learning how to do this, as I haven't found anything yet aside from instructions on how to shorten links in WordPress. My goal is to create a page where visitors enter a link and we return a shortened link with tracking analytics, basically, a custom knock-off Bit.ly. I have done a lot of research but come up empty except for this question: [Auto Link shorting via PHP&AJAX (bit.ly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910562/auto-link-shorting-via-phpajax-bit-ly), which is unfortunately not quite what I'm looking for. This has to be done in WordPress, and I've read through dozens of WordPress forums with no luck yet. Obviously, a solution would be welcome, but I'm really just trying to find a place to start researching/learning how to do this (especially since I have no useful research yet to offer).
Thanks!

Comment: The first result that I googled up is this plugin: [URL Shortify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-shortify/). Probably does everything you need.

Comment: You know, I read through over 30 URL shortening plugins and for some reason, never saw that they have a public facing option in their premium options. Thank you for this! And for not making me feel as stupid as I probably should ;)
Also, you deserve points for the answer, as simple as it may be. I'll accept it right away if you add it as an answer :)

Comment: No need to feel stupid. It’s sometimes impossible to find and pick the right plugin in the Wordpress universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [URL Shortify – Simple, Powerful and Easy URL Shortener Plugin For WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/url-shortify/).