# Event in Jquery that check if the user has stopped typing his/her input

Tags: jquery

Is there an event or a method in jquery that check if the user has finished inputting the input box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)

Comment: You are looking for [`blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) method.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is when the user leaves the input field: https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `focusout` function that `JQuery` providing for you :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").focusout(function(){
        alert('finished')
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  input: <input type="text" id="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, lovely idea