# Keyup show success-message one time

Tags: php, jquery, html, keyup

I have a text-area which saves the data in my database every-time the user hits a key or writes inside the text-area . My problem is that when i want to show a success message like "saved" in a `<p>` it repeats itself every-time someone hits a key, i want it to repeatedly show the same message under but only one time.

If possible may remove the "saved" message on success after 10 seconds.

This is what i mean:
 [image: I want to remove this "LAGRET"]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="comment">Kommentar:</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
  <p name="message" id="message"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#comment").keyup(function (){
    var isTyping = $('#comment').val();
    var data = 'result=' + isTyping;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "commentsave.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){  
           $('#message').append('Saved');

        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['result'];
echo $name;
```

Thank you very much, dont need you to code for me but just guide me :)

Comment: Various concerns with this approach aside from your issue.  This is going to fire potentially frequently.  You may want to debounce this logic so you are not firing for *every* key.  Also what if the key was like shift?  Or another key that didn't change the value (arrow keys are common)?  there is an 'input' event that ignores those.   Secondly, what if I paste something in there?  It's an outlier, but your logic as wouldn't handle for it.

Comment: That's way too much AJAX requests. Delay AJAX request for a second or two, if user decides to not type anymore, then send the AJAX request. [Answer to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing).

Comment: I agree with both of you, still a learner and now i learned something new. Ill add a delay for few seconds the answer by Alive to die will anyway show if the message was saved or not, i remove the message "saved" after a few seconds also so the user wont be confused if its saved or not. Ill just set a delay right before ajax request right. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:-

```
$('#message').append('Saved');
```

to:-

```
$('#message').html('Saved');
```

Note:- `append()` added the new data into the existing-one inside an element, that's why multiple successful messages shown.

While `html()` will remove old data from element first and then add new-one. So no-repetition will happen.

Please try to read every comment under your post and try to implement them for improvement.Specially not sending ajax call on each key-up. It will broke your system at-some point of time.

Comment: Thank you very much, dont know why i didnt think of this!

Comment: @Asim  glad to help you:):). every-one learn slowly.so don't worry