# How to validate onkeyup event without again and again sending post request to route in larravel

Tags: ajax, validation, laravel-5, request, onkeyup

validate Activity function with Ajax code

```
$(document).on('keyup','#activity_name',function () {
            var error_activity = '';
            var activity = $('#activity_name').val();
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : '{{ url('checkactivity') }}',
                data :{activity:activity, _token:_token},
                success:function (result) {
                    if(result == 'unique'){
                        $('#activity_status').html('<lable class="text-sucess" style="color: blue"></lable>');
                        $('#activity').removeClass('has-error');
                        $('#activity_btn').attr('disabled',false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#activity_status').html('<lable class="text-danger">Try Another!</lable>');
                        $('#activity').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#activity_btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

My input field and here he is always call an event Onkeyup when ever i enters a single word in my input field and on each word he is sending a post request.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="checkbox">Group</label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm"  id="activitygroup" name="activitydeleverable">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    @foreach(App\Groups::all() as $group_name)
                        <option value="{{ $group_name->id }}">{{ $group_name->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>      
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="activity_btn" onclick="insertactivity()" class="btn btn-info">Insert</button>
```

here is my Controller Function

```
function checkactivity(Request $request){
    $data = Activities::whereName($request->activity)->first();
    if (!is_null($data)){
        echo 'not_unique';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'unique';
    }
}
```

My code is work perfect, but i have a problem. On each single word my onkeyup Event Ajax send a post request to db and check data is available in db or not. but i have to stop this to doing again and again Post request. it's may do slow my system so i have to solve this please solve this logical issue i have to stop this Post requests or need only one post request.
 [You can see no of request in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3esJJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You will find all the information regarding your desired solution in this solved question:

[How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)

Answer (score 0):

proper way of doing ajax request is use make it single at a time.

```
var req = null;
$(document).on('keyup','#activity_name',function () {
            var error_activity = ''; 
            var activity = $('#activity_name').val();
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
            if (req != null) req.abort();
            req = $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                url : '{{ url('checkactivity') }}',
                data :{activity:activity, _token:_token},
                success:function (result) {
                    if(result == 'unique'){
                        $('#activity_status').html('<lable class="text-sucess" style="color: blue"></lable>');
                        $('#activity').removeClass('has-error');
                        $('#activity_btn').attr('disabled',false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#activity_status').html('<lable class="text-danger">Try Another!</lable>');
                        $('#activity').addClass('has-error');
                        $('#activity_btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make it delay method.

```
function delay(fn, ms) {
  let timer = 0
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(fn.bind(this, ...args), ms || 0)
  }
}
```

```
$('#input').keyup(delay(function (e) {
  console.log('Time elapsed!', this.value);
}, 500));
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
    <label for="input">Try it:
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type something here..."/>
    </label>
```