# Show an alert when a user stops typing in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I want to show an alert message in ReactJS when the user stops typing in a a form field.

Comment: You need not to think specific to reactjs in this situation. This is to be done with pure js way with a listener on input box.

Comment: Sure , it will be no problem . If this can be done with pure JS . it will be ok

Comment: Like this :  <input type="text" onblur="alert('x')">

Comment: Do you mean an alert dialog box, that's not going to be very nice UI.  If you mean some form of alert info box, that wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I mean to say when User stopped typing I want to display alert message

Comment: This should give you the answer, as others have said it's not specific to React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing?rq=1

Comment: @Joru , Yes because all answer is given through Jquery

Comment: @Jon you only need the first part of that answer - the `delay` function. That will be your React event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q5b63z) can help you.

This kind of features are not React specific, so you can achieve that in many ways with JS.

Simple component :

```
    class App extends Component {
      typingTimer = null;

     handleChange = (evt) => {
       const val = evt.target.value;
       clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
       this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (val) {
          window.alert('Stopped typing !');
        }
       }, 500);
     }
     componentWillUnmount() {
       clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
     }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: The main contents of your answer appear to be located at your link.  [To make your answer robust, please copy the relevant information from your link into your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/133286).

Comment: That's great.  Thank you for the improvement @AbdelkarimELAMEL .

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL . Can you please help me how to stop alert when user remove text from input . Here When I stopped the typing alert is working fine but when I removed text from input it occur again . I just want to show alert on stopping typing not like user removed text

Answer (score 2):

Here, I created React functional component for my use.

```js
const App = () => {
  let typingTimer = null;

  const makeAnApiCall =(inputValue) => {
        console.log("Making an Ajax Call");
        window.alert('Making an Ajax Call');
    }
  
  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const val = evt.target.value;
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (val) {
        makeAnApiCall(val)
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    }
  }, [])

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} /> 
      </div>
    );
}
```

Workgin demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-api-when-typing-stop-in-react)