# PHP MySQL AngularJS extract a word after user has stopped typing from table rows

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have an input box for search in my website which outputs instant results using an `AngularJS` search function on `ng-keyup` event. The condition for search in the PHP file is the search string more than 3 characters and more than one search result found. If these conditions are met the PHP file inserts a row in the keyword table with the number of results for each search.  The advantage of this is to show the user instant search results while typing, but the disadvantage is that the different parts of a word are recorded in multiple table rows as follows:

```
Keywordsearch Table
----------------------------------------
keyword   results          datetime
----------------------------------------
cha         45       2019-09-06 10:55:19 
char        33       2019-09-06 10:55:19
chari       28       2019-09-06 11:03:12
charit      22       2019-09-06 11:24:04
charity     14       2019-09-06 11:34:44
----------------------------------------
```

My question: Is there a way in PHP, MySQL or AngularJS to extract the complete words after the user has stopped typing as `charity` from the `keyword column` from the `keywordsearch table` in this example, in order to output them in the most searched keywords section of my website?

Comment: Define 'sense'.

Comment: understandable or is found in the dictionary or a complete word

Comment: 'Char' means to burn; it's also a data type. 'Chari' is a river in Africa . 'Charit' is a creek in Tennessee. So, given the correct context, all these terms are understandable.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the target is to get the complete word the user meant after he completed typing which is charity in this example

Comment: But you see the problem

Comment: You mean the question should be how to get the word after which the user has stopped typing

Comment: This question is too vague in my opinion. Perhaps that's your problem in the first place: You only have a vague idea of what you want. If you cannot exactly explain what you want, we will struggle to help you.

Comment: Why the idea is clear, simply how to get the completed words from DB after which the user has finished typing

Comment: I have an answer for this here: "How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?" https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494269/2430549

Comment: Yes I agree this the solution, please added as a solution to accept as the solution. Thanks