# How to add Delay to oninput in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having the following Function where user hits inputs new Key, the save into the DB., but the problem is im input are getting saved into db as 1,12,123,124,1245,12456...and so on? how can i input the value as a whole. ?

```
 wo_input.oninput = function() {
            if (wo_input.value) {
                if (wo_input.value.length > 0) {
                    saveOnChange(wo_input.value, 'wo_number');
                } else { }
            } else { }
        }
```

Save on Change Function

```
function saveOnChange(val, type) {
    var diagnosis_id = $('#diagnosis_id').val();
    console.log(val + " : " + type + " : " + diagnosis_id);
    $.post('/diagnosis/saveOnChange', {
        '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        'diagnosis_id': diagnosis_id,
        'value': val,
        'type': type
    }, function(success) {
        console.log(success);
        if (success.redirect) {
            //window.location.href = '/diagnosis/edit/' + success.id;
            window.history.pushState('edit', 'Title', '/diagnosis/edit/'+success.id);
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="saveonchange add_media id_input" type="text" name="wo_number" value="" id="wo_input"/>
```

Comment: use the `onchange` event instead? That gets executed when the element loses focus.

Comment: Yes, `onchange` Works but this has to feel dynamic, so that value will be saved after like 5 secs after no typing.

Comment: Search for "debouncing"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to save the whole value once the user finished typing, and not every time the user presses a key.

You could use jQuery's change event:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

Inputs also have a blur event you may check out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: Yes, `onchange` Works but this has to feel dynamic, so that value will be saved after like 5 secs after no typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` to check after a certain delay if there where no changes after that delay. If there where none then save it to your database.

Using `new Date().getTime()` you get the amount of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 which you can use for your check.

Below example logs a console message when there was no input for 2 seconds.

```js
const ms = 2000;

$('#test').on('input', (e) => {
  $(e.currentTarget).data('updated', new Date().getTime());
  setTimeout(() => { 
    if(new Date().getTime() - ms >= $(e.currentTarget).data('updated')) {
      console.log(`${ms}ms past. Go save!`);
    }
  }, ms);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
```