# Wait x seconds for new emitted value before triggering a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a child component that emits a value, and in the parent I perform an axios call with this value each time it is emitted. My problem is that I want to trigger the axios call only if in x ms (or seconds) the child has not emmited another value in order to reduce the amount of calls I do.

Code here :

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

import DataTable from './DataTable.vue';

export default {
    name: 'Test',
    data() {
        return {
            gamertags: [],

            // Utils
            timeout: 500,
            delay: 500
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // API calls
        async getGamerTags(string='') {
            const path = `http://localhost:5000/gamertags?string=${string}`
            await axios.get(path)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.gamertags = res.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        },

        // DataTable
        handleFilters(filters) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
            this.timeout = setTimeout(this.getGamerTags(filters.find(o => o.field == "playerGamerTag").filter), this.delay);
        }
    }
    components: {
        DataTable
    }
};
</script>

<template>
    <DataTable
        @filters="handleFilters"
    />
</template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debouncing is what you are looking for https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce.

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function as a first argument. You are not passing a function, you are calling your function and passing it's result into `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [debouncing](https://medium.com/@jamischarles/what-is-debouncing-2505c0648ff1). Here is an example:

```js
var timeout, delay = 3000;

function func1() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    alert("3000 ms inactivity");
  }, delay);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="func1()">
```

When emitted, simply call `func1()`, and if there are no new emissions after 3000 ms, the function in timeout will be executed.

Comment: I added my code, and your solution seems to not work. Like the function is triggering every time a value is emitted, and after 500 ms i have this error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier```

Comment: @hitaton, I've added a snippet into my answer, and it works normally.

Comment: @hitaton, furthermore, the syntax error might be caused by a missing or unneeded comma, semicolon or other identifiers in your original code.

Comment: So i figured that I should change my code to ```this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {this.getGamerTags(filters.find(o => o.field == "playerGamerTag").filter);}, this.delay);``` but with that I have the error ```TypeError: this.getGamerTags is not a function```

Comment: Ok my bad, I just did not know how to use setTimeout function with params. I posted an answer to my post. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to understand the problem and use case if you add the code also.
but As I could understand the problem these is two way

1. if you using inside input and triggering based `@changed` event you can add `@change.lazy` this not trigger on each change.
2. second solution is to use `setTimeout(function,delayInMs)` inside parent

[vuejs Docs link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#lazy)

Comment: ```@change.lazy``` is not what I want, I want something like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing
And i added code in the post

Answer (score 0):

By simply changing the `handleFilters` function to :

```
handleFilters(filters) {
   clearTimeout(this.timeout);
   this.timeout = setTimeout(
      this.getGamerTags,
      this.delay,
      filters.find(o => o.field == "playerGamerTag").filter
   );
},
```

the problem is solved.