# How to carry out a search as the user types into a textfield?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax and PHP to perform a search and return the result as the user types.

I have tried using

```
$("#search text"). focus(function() {
    if( searchtext!='' && searchtext !="search our products"){
        $('#searchdisplay').slideDown();
        var datasrting = 'searchtext ='+searchtext;
        $.Ajax({
           type: POST ,
           url: "http://>>localhost<</hishighnex/assync/search.php" ,
           data: datastring ,
           success:function(response){
               alert(response);
           }
       })
    })
}
```

but it only picks value when click out of the text field and back into the text field. It was not alerting anything. Yet it was not as asynchronous. Also how can I put the result back into the `<div>` I created for it?

Comment: Possible solution using javascript and jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/javascript-jquery-make-an-ajax-request-when-a-user-is-typing-in-a-textarea

Comment: Going through your edit, I noticed there's quite a few JavaScript Syntax errors you've got to get fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to do it, you will have to change it for your own needs:

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <h3>The Happy Eater</h3>
    Enter the food you would like to order:
    <input type="text" id="userInput" />
    <div id="underInput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The index takes an input field with an ID (this is where you type) the output is the div with ID underInput.

JavaScript File:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
var xmlHttp;

if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
else
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}

if(!xmlHttp)
    alert("Cant create that object");
else
    return xmlHttp;
}

function process()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
    food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
else
{
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}
}

function handleServerResponse()
 {
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
    if(xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Something Went Wrong!');
    }
}
}
```

the javascript file checks the input and then sends that information to the background php file which does the work in php and returns the result in XML format. The javascript file then takes the result and updates the index.php. after the function is called when the page is loaded, it keeps running once every second (can be changed) which will give the impression that its updating live so you dont have to click outside the text box for the field to update.

Background PHP File:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna', 'bacon', 'beef', 'loaf', 'ham');
    if(in_array($food, $foodArray))
        echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';
    elseif($food=='')
        echo 'Enter a food you idiot';
    else
        echo 'Sorry We Dont Sell '.$food.'!';
echo '</response>';
?>
```

the background php file returns everything in XML format.

This above method is similar to how google have their live search update.

-*This code is taken from a [The New Boston Tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=61*)

Answer (score 0):

Check the TokenInput plugin http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ or the Autocomplete widget from JqueryUI http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Both are easy to integrate to your site and has nice features.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your search working, you need to define more than one event handler.

You call your function `slideDown()` correctly on focus.

The ajax search request must not be called on focus, but rather on keyup event. You have to check that there is at least one or two characters, before sending the request. Also take care to cancel the previous request, if it didn't get already a response (depending on your implementation, this could be done automatically).

Last, on blur event, you have to call a function, that hides your `#searchdisplay` again.