# Validating input fields. Usability

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, usability

I am doing site, which will help people to collect their 
water meters readings. At the moment I am doing input form for adding current month readings.

Browser is checking data when user input it, not on/after form sending (via jquery). For example, user inputted `123` and pressed `d` after. After he pressed `d` error will appear near input field etc... So field is validating on `keyup` action

I am thinking about adding test, that will be passed if user inputted value, that is not lesser then previous month (or not previous month, just last inputted) value.

So imagine: Last month meter value was 250. Current 255. Input field is blank. User staring print. He pressing `2` (inputted value is `2` now). Remember that value is being tested on key up? jQuery will start test and will return error because 2 (current value in field) < 250 (last month meter value). After that he pressing `5` (inputted value is `25` now). 25 < 250, so jquery will still show error, that value, user inputting is invalid. After that he printing `5` again (now value inputted is `255`). 255 not < then 250, so error message/block will disappear.

So the question is such: is it correct to show error on keyup for this test (checking if inputted value is less then last month value)? I think it is not rly correct, because some users are very newb to pc's and this message can scare them or idk :))) 
Is it okay or should I find a way to test this only on `onblur` action (remove focus from field)? But will it be too late to show error message (I mean usability ofc)? I am checking inputs when ppl input their data because of better usability (so ppl know about his mistake on input stage, not after sending form).

Maybe there are another suggestion?

Comment: Questions asking us for opinions are not allowed on StackOverflow.  It's best to present very specific questions rather than "what is best?" or presenting various hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: If you're using jQuery Validate, none of the validation would occur until after the initial "submit" event.  Then `onkeyup` and `onblur` come into play. There are ways to disable or modify these events but I cannot post a specific answer to such a generic question.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 events, one onkeyup and one onblur? The onkeyup can check for incorrect characters and the onblur can compare the input value to last month

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout to the keyup, this is a possible duplicate of this same issue:

[How to trigger an onkeyup event that's delayed until a user pauses their typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/javascript-jquery-make-an-ajax-request-when-a-user-is-typing-in-a-textarea)

Comment: May be it is nice suggestion. Found this issue exactly for this plugin [link](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/466), but it is not still done. Any suggestion how I can use onkeyup delay on my code? Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvAs5/). There are no remote test, but can you help with `digits` for example? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post again in the jsFiddle? I thought it was validating but it is not now.

I'm hoping to wrap it in something like this:

 var delay=2500 // 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){

    //your code to be executed after 2.5 seconds
    }, delay)

Comment: What do u mean? This is jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/95kgu/ . It is validating okay atm.

Comment: Simply linking to another SO answer is not an acceptable answer.  I'll retract my down-vote if you'll edit your answer to be fully "self-contained".