# Debounce for 500ms if True else execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, debouncing

Spoiler; I'm completely new to jQuery/Javascript.

I have a boolean field `CheckMe` and an input field `textField`.

If `textField` is empty, `CheckMe` should not be shown else it should (this means if goes from not-empty to empty `CheckMe` should be hidden right away again). I want to parse a delay, say 500 ms, i.e `CheckMe` is shown if `text` is not empty and after 500 ms of the last keypress

I have tried using the debounce function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620602/how-to-trigger-an-onkeyup-event-thats-delayed-until-a-user-pauses-their-typing) SO answer (see my implementation below), but the problem is, `CheckMe` is also first hidden after 500 ms of `textField` being empty

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function debounce(fn, duration) {
  var timer;
  return function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, duration);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    const textField= $("#textField");
    const CheckMe= $("#CheckMe");
    CheckMe.hide();

    textField.on("input", debounce(()=> {
      if (textField.val()) {
        CheckMe.show();
      } else {
        CheckMe.hide();
      }
    },500));
});
</script>
```

but that removes `checkMe` after 500 ms when I clear `textField`.

I have tried moving the debounce into the True statement i.e

```js
...
   textField.on("input", function() {
      if (textField.val()) {
        debounce(function(){CheckMe.show();},500)
      
      } else {

        CheckMe.hide();
      }
}
```

but that does not show `CheckMe` at any point

Comment: Please clarify: you want to it appear 500ms after someone stops typing.  But you want it to disappear immediately (as soon as input is clear, but not after 500ms)?

Comment: Correct - appear after 500 ms when user stops typing, but disappear the second `textField` is empty, i.e the call `CheckMe.hide()` should never be delayed but `CheckMe.show()` should be delayed 500 ms after the user stops typing

Comment: You might need to include some HTML / a snippet.  What's the relation between `priceThreshold` and `textField` - are they the same just a typo in the question?

Comment: Just a typo - I have editted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the attempt with `if () { debouce(()={}); } else { immediate(); }` doesn't work is due to how event handlers store the function and how debounce stores its timer.

When you run `.on("input", function() { }`) that function definition is stored within the event handler, ready to run.   However with debounce, that's not what is being done, instead it's:

```
.on("input", function())
```

there's no function *definition* - it calls the function itself, which happens to return another function to be called when the event runs.

It's why there there are so many questions on SO saying something like "my code runs immediately when I do `.on("input", myfunction())` when it should be `.on("input", myfunction)`

So that one function (the debounce) runs *once* per event setup - not once per `input` event fire, but just once when setting up the event.  So there's only one instance of `var timer` and it's all contained within the debounce function.   The event fire then calls the code inside the `return function()` which already has `var timer` defined previously in its outer scope (the previous debounce call).

If you call debounce again with a 2nd input `$("#secondInp").on("input", debounce(() => ...` you get a second instance of the function with its own variable (so they don't conflict between inp1 and inp2).

So you can then see that if you put this inside the event handler (in the `if`), you're calling a *new* debounce each time (not the same one).

Your attempt did nothing because your code `debounce(function(){CheckMe.show();},500)` simply returns the function - so you would need to do

```
debounce(function(){CheckMe.show();},500)();`
```

but even that won't work as *each time* it's called (each event) you get a new instance of the debounce function and a new instance of `var timer`.

---

You can use two events.  Inside each event check if the "check me" should be shown or not.

The `debounce`d one will run after 500ms and the not-debounced one will run immediately.

```js
function debounce(fn, duration) {
  var timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, duration);
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  const textField = $("#textField");
  const checkMe = $("#checkMe");
  checkMe.hide();

  textField.on("input", debounce(() => {
    if (textField.val()) {
      checkMe.show();
    }
  }, 500));

  textField.on("input", () => {
    if (!textField.val()) {
      checkMe.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#checkMe { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textField" type="text">
<div id='checkMe'>^-- check this</div>
```

---

> is it possible to keep it in a single if-else

Given the explanation above, it is not possible using your `debounce` function as it is; because of the `return function() { }` and the single instance of `timer`.  The key being the *single instance of `timer`*.

Without the debounce, this can be implemented in a single function, using an *outer* variable for the timer, but will need the debounce code repeated each time (eg for a 2nd input) - just the clearTimeout and setTimeout code - so not much - it's the "global"/outer-scope variable that becomes an issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var textFieldTimer = null;
  
  const textField = $("#textField");
  const checkMe = $("#checkMe");
  checkMe.hide();

  textField.on("input", () => {
    if (textField.val()) {
      clearTimeout(textFieldTimer);
      textFieldTimer = setTimeout(() => checkMe.show(), 500);
    }
    else {
      checkMe.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#checkMe { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textField" type="text">
<div id='checkMe'>^-- check this</div>
```

---

So how can we use both: a reusable function and inside an `if` inside the event handler?

By storing the *single instance of `timer`* on the element itself - using `.data()` in the code below, but any method to store a single instance per element will also work.

Here's an example, using a single event with an `if` and repeated for a second input to show how it might work.

```js
function debounce2(fn, duration)
{
    var timer = $(this).data("timer");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).data("timer", setTimeout(fn, duration));
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkMe, #checkMe2").hide();

  $("#textField, #textField2").on("input", function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      debounce2.call(textField, () => $("#checkMe").show(), 500);
    }
    else {
      $("#checkMe").hide();
    }
  });



  // second input confirming `timer` is per element.
  
  $("#textField2").on("input", function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      debounce2.call(textField, () => $("#checkMe2").show(), 500);
    }
    else {
      $("#checkMe2").hide();
    }
  });  
});
```

```css
#checkMe, #checkMe2 { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textField" type="text">
<div id='checkMe'>^-- check this</div>
<hr/>
<input id="textField2" type="text">
<div id='checkMe2'>^-- check this</div>
```

Comment: Aaah yes - that works! But isn't it possible to keep it in an if-else? Just to make it more readable

Comment: That's not how `return function()` and event handlers work.  I'll add some details..